# App to lock phone

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope, asking-questions

I’m looking for apps which lock the phone, either for a specific app (I.e. “don’t use Facebook for 1 day”) or for the full phone (I.e., “don’t use any app for the whole day”). On Android this is doable with Offtime. On iOS Offtime (conveniently renamed to “Offtime light”) is totally useless (it doesn’t lock anything at all). Then:

1. Can I ask a question for an app who would achieve the same? I guess I can’t, app recommendations would be off-topic here. But would they be on-topic sonewhere else?
2. Can I ask details about Flipd? Flipd is an app which should do what I need (I think) at the price of installing an MDM certificate on my phone. For legal reasons, I cannot risk access by third parties to documents or emails on my phone. So I need to know if installing MDM certificates for Flipd exposes me to such a risk , and if it’s possible to revoke the MDM certificate authorization. Would such a question be acceptable for the main site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is general guidance.

- [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation)
- [What exactly is a recommendation question on Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question-on-ask-different)

So absolutely you can ask one or both questions. They might be closed though if they are either too vague or broad. I would start with the one question that’s got some research you can show and define what tasks to need to do and better if you can link to the closest app you found and then explain why it doesn’t meet your criteria. Should one get closed, you already know about meta for asking for editing help or guidance.