# How to improve this question

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

This question was closed:

[Free WYSIWYG Markdown editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451040/free-wysiwyg-markdown-editor)

with the motivation

```
Questions asking to recommend or find a Mac, book, tool, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Ask Different as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit this question to describe the problem and what research has been done so far to solve it.
```

On the other hand, software recommendations are on topic here, as explained in

https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3236/272604

so I guess the issue is with the lack of research and/or problem description. Would this be better? If not, can you help me improve it? Finally, should I migrate to Super User in your opinion? I'm not sure why to allow software recommendations here, if the best course of action is to ask on Super User, but no matter: if you think I should ask there instead than here, I'll definitely migrate the question.

---

I've been using Typora as a Markdown editor when it was free (during beta), but now it's pay for use and I want to find an equivalent, free (preferably open source) tool. My requirements:

- free (preferably open source)
- rather than a separate editing and preview pane, I want the editing to happen in the same pane in which the  Markdown code is rendered, i.e., WYSIWYG. This is what Typora does
- support for drawing tables, bulleted/numbered lists, code fences, import images, etc. Basically, the same features as the post editor on Stack Exchange, but WYSIWYG instead than separate editing/preview panes
- rendering of math formulas
- runs on Monterey

Research: I googled around a bit and I found the following;

- [Mou app](http://mouapp.com/) seemed to have been widely recommended in the past, but it's not being developed anymore
- [MacDown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/) is active, but it has separated editing and rendering panes
- similarly for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown)

Comment: no comments? I proposed my edits for review. I hope they're well-received, or otherwise that I'll get some suggestions on how to improve it here.

Comment: With the edits the question IMHO is on-topic.

Comment: @nohillside thanks!